# Driver change doesn't persist

Tags: drivers, nic

I want to change my NIC driver to an older version to have wol activate. I'm talking about alx driver.
I did this process on debian and after a lot of tries I could get it working and the change persisted.
Now, in Lubuntu (kodibuntu version) I have the driver compiled and it works, the wol is supported when I change the driver manually.
The problem is that after restart the kernel driver version is applied!!
This is the steps I follow:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules_install
```

Now I have my new driver compiled and:

```
rmmod alx
insmod alx.ko
ethtool -s eth0 wol g
```

WOL now works, before the change it didn't. To make the change persistent I remove the default alx.ko module from the kernerl/drivers/... folder and I copy my compiled module there:

```
rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
cp alx.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
```

May be I have mistaken then routes, but I'm writting in memory, now I don't have the Ubuntu PC here.

I apreciate your help, I would like to have the wol persistent after power off or restart. I had to make a lot of tries to get it working in debian but in Ubuntu I can't get it.
Thanks! Gonzalo.

Comment: After restart the kernel module is loaded, I use `rmmod alx && modprobe alx` and my module is loaded so the kernel module is being loaded on boot but where is it?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up so I used the easy solution.

I create an alx script in `/etc/init.d` and when the system starts it loads the new module driver.